# Как подключить библиотеку boost в windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost, cmakelists

Как подключить boost? Имеем чистую windows 10. У нас нету и не будет microsoft visual studio.
У нас будет mingw и CMakeLists.txt. Нужно статически подключить boost к проекту.
Как это сделать быстро и элегантно ? К примеру, нужна работа с thread.
Но не работает линковка:

```
undefined reference to `boost::thread::get_id() undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::get_id() undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept
```

Я попробую дать минимальный пример main.cpp.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::thread some_thread=make_thread(); 
    some_thread.join(); 
    return 0;
}
```

И пример CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Test VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(PROJECT_NAME "Test")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)

set(BOOST_ROOT D:/boost_1_80_0)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wall - 
Werror")
set(SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
include_directories("D:/boost_1_80_0")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME}  ${LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

**Добавлю по теме.**
Вот ссылка на документацию https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Там написано

> To compile anything in Boost, you need a directory containing the
> boost\ subdirectory in your #include path. Specific steps for setting
> up #include paths in Microsoft Visual Studio follow later in this
> document; if you use another IDE, please consult your product's
> documentation for instructions.

Я использую VSCode значит мне теперь страдать? А если я буду делать автоматическую сборку в контейнере? Очень хочется получить совет кто реально его использует в работе.

**Частичный ответ.**
Может кому будет полезно.
Нужно скачать архив буста. Разархивировать его куда угодно.
Отредактировать файл bootstap.bat а именно 2 стоки должны быть такими 1) call .\build.bat gcc
2) SET TOOLSET=gcc

```
из cmd запустить bootstrap.bat

из cmd запустить .\b2 toolset=gcc link=static --prefix=boost_lib install
```

Соберутся библиотеки boost и поместятся в каталог boost_lib.
Далее для CMakeList.txt можно подключить примерно так:

```
file(GLOB LIBRARIES
    "D:/boost_1_80_0/boost_lib/lib/libboost_thread-mgw10-mt-x64-1_80.a"
)
```

Осталось решить как это можно сделать проще.

Comment: Минимальный пример должен содержать команды компилятору и лог сборки.

Comment: Хорошо, я дал минимальный пример. Если этого не достаточно, вы не могли бы мне дать свой минимальный пример, где у вас все работает без ошибок?

Comment: Это не похоже на минимальный пример.  Команды компилятору и лог сборки отсутствуют. С таким сборочным скриптом компилятор должен был пожаловаться на то, что не может найти библиотеки буст, так как не указано их расположение.

Comment: Что по вашему тут не похоже? CMakeList является инструкцией для компилятора. Он же и список команд компилятору. Посмотрите пожалуйста внимательнее. Все пути прописаны.

Comment: Эм, нет. CMakeList компилятором никак не используется. На основе этого скрипта генерируется скрипт, который генерирует команды компилятору (например ninja). Затем при выполнении этого второго скрипта запускается компилятор. И чтобы видеть его команды следует включать verbose режим. И привести лог сборки. А пути к библиотекам не прописаны.

Comment: Да потому что этих библиотек то и нет.  И путей до них тоже соответственно нет. А для чего смотреть лог сборки если все и так очевидно? Вопрос, как подключить библиотеку.

Comment: *"все и так очевидно"* - читающим вопрос ничего не очевидно. Вопросы должны быть составлены так, чтобы читающие могли получить такой же результат ничего не додумывая. А у вас тут не воспроизводимости нет, ни даже лога сборки чтобы хоть как-то разобраться в происходящем, раз у себя это не воспроизвести. ¿т.е. как это библиотек нет? ¿А что вы собираетесь линковать тогда? ¿Может вы вообще boost не собирали перед своим проектом?